# A simple, easy to use FTP client for non-techical clients?

Tags: windows, ftp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an absolutely idiot-proof Windows FTP client?](https://superuser.com/questions/108094/is-there-an-absolutely-idiot-proof-windows-ftp-client)

As the title suggests: Does anyone know of a FTP client which would be easy for a less technical person to use? I've been asked to do a little research into the topic and so far haven't found much. 
I'm wondering if there's an FTP client out there which offers the follow:

> - A graphical interface of all the files on the server (or maybe even bigger icons to make them easy to differentiate)
> - Displays a message/confirmation dialog box that the file they uploaded has been successfully uploaded.

I'm open to all mediums, it can be a Windows application or something completely web based.
I'm sure this could potentially help some other people too!

Comment: Windows Explorer has FTP functionality - if you set up a shortcut, the regular drag/drop/copy/paste will work.

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not, try it, you may find that Windows itself built into it, has the easiest to use GUI.   Open any folder-window and in the address textbox, where it normally has the folder, type-

```
ftp://host
```

then it asks for user/pass

You can drag and drop too. You can double click say a txt file, it opens in notepad, write in it close it.. it will save on the FTP server. No fuss. It's quite seamless.

There is also FTP Explorer which might've been free at one time but now has a 30 day trial

Maybe the more complex ones help for changing between active/passive ftp.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if they satisfy all your needs, but may I suggest a few good choices?

FlashFXP: http://www.flashfxp.com/ (Very good standalone Windows client)

FireFTP: http://fireftp.mozdev.org/ (Pretty amazing Firefox extension from Mozilla)

I hope it helps!